# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The problems:

> 111. Prove that $$\frac{\sin^3 a}{\sin b} + \frac{\cos^3 a}{\cos b} \geqslant \sec (a-b),$$ for all $a,b \in \bigl(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$.
> 112. Prove that $$\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt[3]{abc}} \geqslant \frac{(a+b+c+\sqrt[3]{abc})^2}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)},$$ for all $a,b,c > 0$.

Can someone give me a hint for the two problems. They are all based on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
Just a hint.

Comment: what is `sec()` ?

Comment: @Thomas, secant, I suppose

Comment: Yes! That's the normal notation.

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question but it would help others too.   After expanding the denominator on the right hand side and using cauchy-schwarz gives the required inequality

Comment: You should ask two different questions in two posts, not one.

Answer (score 1):

One form of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is

$$\sum_i^n \frac{x_i^2}{y_i}\ge \frac{\left(\sum_i^n x_i\right)^2}{\sum_i^n y_i}\tag 1$$

Let $n=2$ and $x_1=\sin^2a$, $x_2=\cos^2a$, $y_1=\sin a\sin b$, and $y_2=\cos a\cos b$

The result follows immediately after expanding $\sec (a-b)=\frac{1}{\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b}$

To see this explicitly, we use $(1)$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_i^n \frac{x_i^2}{y_i}&=\frac{\sin^4 a}{\sin a \sin b}+\frac{\cos^4 a}{\cos a\cos b}\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\sin^3a}{\sin b}+\frac{\cos^3 a}{\cos b}}\\\\
&\ge \frac{\left(\sum_i^n x_i\right)^2}{\sum_i^n y_i}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin^2 a +\cos^2 a}{\sin a\sin b+\cos a\cos b}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\cos(a-b)}\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sec(a-b)}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer for (1). For (2), note by Cauchy Schwarz inequality,
$$LHS = \sum_{cyc} \frac{c^2}{c^2(a+b)}+\frac{(\sqrt[3]{abc})^2}{2abc} \ge \frac{(a+b+c+\sqrt[3]{abc})^2}{\sum_{cyc} c^2(a+b) + 2abc}$$

and further the denominator factorises as
$$\sum_{cyc} c^2(a+b) + 2abc = (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

Comment: Very well done!